# How let chrome app extension continue scripting after changing page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, google-chrome-extension

i'm developing a chrome app that a certain point clicks on a link and go to another page (of the same website) but the script doesn't continue ( i have to re click on the chrome app and re start everyting) , is there a way to let it continue ?

This is my manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Button Click",  
"description": "Be able to press buttons",  
"version": "1.0",    
"browser_action": { 
    "default_icon": "images/icons/16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"  
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
```

}

Comment: Declare a background script in manifest.json so your popup script will send a message to it, and the background script will run the first content script (which can save the state in chrome.storage.local), then wait for the tab to update via chrome.tabs.onUpdated, then run the second content script (which can reuse the state from chrome.storage.local). There are several answers on StackOverflow that show how to do it in detail so I think you'll be able to find them. BTW the background script may not be strictly necessary in your case.

Comment: @wOxxOm  thk you for your answer , i have searched a lot but i haven't find nothing about continue after getting a new page